# Правильно ли я корректирую движение в игре при падении fps?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, cocos2d, cocos2d-x, fps

Изучаю движок cocos2d-x, не очень знаком с этой темой, поэтому не уверен, верно ли всё сделал.

Я двигаю спрайт на 5 пикселей 60 раз в секунду и, если фпс упадёт, то я хочу чтобы за секунду спрайт продвинулся на те же 5*60 пикселей, не меньше и не больше. Правильно ли я сделал корректировку движения?

```
void HelloWorld::update(float delta)
{
    float newPosX = sprite->getPositionX() + (xMovement * 5 * delta / 0.016666);
    float newPosY = sprite->getPositionY() + (yMovement * 5 * delta / 0.016666);
    sprite->setPosition(newPosX, newPosY);
}
```

Проверял вставив этот код в функцию `update`, на глаз вроде работает:

```
if (RandomHelper::random_int(1, 100) == 5)
    Sleep(100);
```

Я знаю что сформулировал вопрос плохо, но надеюсь знающие люди поймут. Если есть идеи как это сделать по-другому, с удовольствием прочитаю.

Переменные `xMovement` и `yMovement` имеют значения -1, 0, 1, зависит от нажатых клавиш.

Comment: Судя по коду, `delta` в этом коде - это разница с последнего кадра?

Comment: Полезное чтиво: [Fix Your Timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep).

Comment: @VTT Код увидел [тут](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/10/11/Cocos2d-x-Tutorial-Series-Game-loops-Updates-and-Action-Handling.aspx) и изменил немного

Comment: Нет, корректировка тут сделана неправильно. Суть в том, что при корректной обработке количество fps не должно влиять на игровое положение. А в данном случае из-за погрешностей вычислений с плавающей точной результаты будут расходится тем сильнее, чем больше разница fps. По методам корректировки можно написать целую книгу, но суть в том, что delta во всех случаях должна быть либо фиксированная, либо абсолютная и обычно необходимо независимое обновление игрового положения и отображения игрового положения.

Comment: @VTT delta - количество времени, прошедшее с предыдущего вызова метода (кадра)

Comment: А нельзя брать время, в которое пытаются отрисовать кадр, ну и по времени вычислить где должен быть спрайт. Начальная позиция есть, скорость вы можете задать (вектор скорости). Нет ?